# ScrollView left and right scrolling With arrow button

Tags: titanium

How to control the vertical scroll using right and left arrow in titanium. How to connect the between the scroll view and right and left arrow

Here is the code:

```
   var counter = 0;
   rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    counter++;

    var wrapperChild = wrapperView.getChildren();

    var scroll2 = verticalScroll.scrollTo(114, 0);
    var scroll1 = verticalScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
    var scroll3 = verticalScroll.scrollTo(307, 0);

    if (counter == 1) {
        verticalScroll.scrollTo(114, 0);
        alert(counter);
    } else if (counter == 2) {
        verticalScroll.scrollTo(307, 0);
        alert(counter);
        //}
    } else if (counter == 3) {
        verticalScroll.scrollTo(417, 0);
        alert(counter);
    } else if (counter == 4) {
        verticalScroll.scrollTo(560, 0);
        alert(counter);
    } else if (counter == 5) {
        verticalScroll.scrollTo(672, 0);
        alert(counter);
    }
});

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (counter == 0)  verticalScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

verticalScroll.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
     Ti.API.info('Scrollview contents y offset: ' + e.x + 'Scrollview contents y offset: ' + e.y);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrollview has a method called `scrollTo( Number x, Number y )`, documented [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-method-scrollTo).

Basically you have to

- create and add the scrollview to the window
- create and add left and right buttons to the window (you might have to set the zIndex if you add the buttons before the scrollview)
- add eventListeners to the buttons that will trigger the scrollTo(). See ["Simple Buttons Example"](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button)

You might be also interested in Titaniums [ScrollableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView)

Comment: Hi Thanks your suggestion Helped me lot. I have added and scrolled to required position. Now i got stucked in one logic scenario. I have added a label first. whenever page focused first label will be in x and y co-ordinates. If I clicks on right arrow i am scrolled to another label. But if i again clicking left arrow it vavigation to first arow corectly. If clicks on right arrow again it should come to second Label but its navigating to third label. Can you show be some example code for this logic?

Comment: Could you provide the code for what you have done so far? I think it would be easier to look for an error there then writing something that completely different.